# Permissions Issue on Wordpress Core Version Upgrade

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, file-permissions

I have a centOS -based virtual machine on digital ocean.
It is running NGINX HTTP sever.
I configured it to use multi domains, and set up SSL.

One of my domains runs a Wordpress application.
I migrated the WordPress files from my godaddy hosting.

Everything works great except when I try to upgrade the wordpress core ( updating and installing plugins works just fine).

When I try to upgrade WordPress to version 5.4.2 I get a permissions error (as shown in attachment photo):

**Permission denied in /var/www/mydomain.com/wordpress/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-filesystem-direct.php on line 281**

[wordpress core upgrade file permissions error display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KbZR.jpg)

I tried doing the following just to diagnose the issue... I have the directory full access to nginx user:
**chmod -R 777 /var/www/**

**chown nginx:nginx /var/www/**

This **did not work**

I made sure php user is nginx by outputting  **echo exec('whoami');** on the page.

I am completely dumbfounded.
Does anyone know what the problem may be?

As a last resort I manually upgraded my wordpress version using FTP, but I'm concerned that I never figured out the root cause of this issue and it will spring back up again opening up a can of worms.

Comment: @esqew wow that fixed it! Thank you! (there was a typo though that I had to edit) **sudo chcon -R --type=httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/mydomain.com**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CentOS includes a mandatory access control (MAC) security mechanism in its Linux kernel by the name of [SELinux](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux). According to [a support forum thread on Wordpress.org](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/update-wordpress-permission-denied-class-wp-filesystem-direct-php/), this mechanism sometimes can cause issues that manifest with this error.

SSH into your server and use the following command to change the SELinux "context" for the entire `/var/www/mydomain.com` folder:

```
chcon -R –-type httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/mydomain.com/
```

The last post in the above-linked thread indicated that this change of context alleviated the errors you're seeing.

As an aside, for your system's security, ensure you change your file permissions back to their defaults.