# Directory Permissions for Docker bind mount using EFS for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-efs

Trying to run a wordpress docker container with EFS as the bind mount on an EC2 instance:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  wp:
    container_name: wp
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: 123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/wp/wordpress:2024.1.3.2
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: ${WORDPRESS_DB_HOST}
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: ${WORDPRESS_DB_NAME}
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: ${WORDPRESS_DB_USER}
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ${WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - /efs/wp/html:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - '9090:80'
```

I have run the following to change the owner / permissions on the directory:

```bash
sudo chown -R ec2-user:ec2-user /efs/wp
sudo chmod 777 /efs/wp -R
```

A few things not working:

1. The back-up plugin is not able to restore because of permission issues (writing to /var/www/html/plugins/...)
2. The admin panel crashes because FTP is not defined and the permissions issue on the directories is making the write to use FTP

If I change to bind mount to use the volume on the host

```yaml
- /data/wp/html:/var/www/html
```

Everything works fine - no permission issues and I can login to the admin panel, restore etc.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63289589/permissions-issue-on-wordpress-core-version-upgrade) post.  I get "operation not supported"

What is it I need to do to be able to use EFS as bind mount so I can have multiple instances running in different availability zones.

Just for completeness - the file system is mounted using the instance profile:

from the

```bash
/etc/fstab
fs-123445555:/ /efs efs _netdev,noresvport,tls,iam 0 0
```